# What is a good way to protect a town from Mobs in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do I use TNT to protect the perimeter like claymores? I built a town with no villagers for a bank, library and a blacksmith's shop. I don't want an Iron Golem because there is no villagers to protect. Any Ideas?

Comment: Protect the town from what?

Comment: why don't you want a golem? a TNT will just scar the area.

Comment: Mobs don't come from outside your town, they come from darkness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stop mobs spawning in your town, the only thing to do is light it up so that the [light level](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Light-emitting_blocks) is above 11 for every solid block. The light level of the block you are standing on is visible by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.

A perimeter wall with an overhang (for spiders) is sufficient to keep all mobs out.

Comment: what is a light level of 11?

Comment: @YoungGuilo See the wiki about light and light level - it's a measure of how much light there is at a certain block. Hostile mobs only spawn when the light level is 11 or below.

Comment: @NightExcessive I reversed your edit. That feature is part of the NEI mod, not Minecraft itself.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wasn't aware. My apologies.

Comment: @NightExcessive No problem! That's why we can all edit these things. I just wanted to let you know why.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It might be worth keeping on there with the side-note that it only works with NEI. I've been using NEI for ages and had absolutely no idea!

Comment: @Dan On a closed question?